# rust lockfree ringbuffer can't work on release mode

Tags: rust, block

I implement a lockfree ringbuffer, and then i test for debug is ok, but in release mode it can't work allways.

```
use std::path::Display;
use std::sync::Arc;


#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct RingBuffer<T, const m_size: usize> {
    idx_head: usize,
    idx_tail: usize,
    m_data: [T; m_size],
}

pub trait Queue<T> {
    fn new_empty() -> Self;
    fn push(&mut self, value: T) -> bool;
    fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<&T>;
    fn is_full(&self) -> bool;
    fn is_empty(&self) -> bool;
}

impl<T, const Size: usize> Queue<T> for RingBuffer<T, Size>
{
    fn new_empty() -> Self {
        RingBuffer::<T, Size> {
            idx_head: 0,
            idx_tail: 0,
            m_data: array_init::array_init(|_| {
                unsafe {
                    std::mem::zeroed()
                }
            }),
        }
    }

    fn push(&mut self, value: T) -> bool {
        let mut head = self.idx_head + 1;
        if head == Size {
            head = 0;
        }
        if head == self.idx_tail {
            return false;
        }
        self.m_data[self.idx_head] = value;
        self.idx_head = head;
        return true;
    }

    fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<&T> {
        let mut tail = self.idx_tail;
        if self.idx_head == tail {
            return None;
        }
        let res = &self.m_data[tail];
        tail += 1;
        if tail == Size {
            tail = 0;
        }
        self.idx_tail = tail;
        return Some(res);
    }

    fn is_full(&self) -> bool {
        self.idx_tail == (self.idx_head + 1) % Size
    }

    fn is_empty(&self) -> bool {
        self.idx_head == self.idx_tail
    }
}

pub struct SharedRingBuffer<T, const m_size: usize> {
    pub ringbuffer: Arc<RingBuffer<T, m_size>>,
}

impl<T, const Size: usize> Clone for SharedRingBuffer<T, Size> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        Self {
            ringbuffer: self.ringbuffer.clone(),
        }
    }
}
impl<T, const Size: usize, > Queue<T> for SharedRingBuffer<T, Size> {
    fn new_empty() -> Self {
        Self {
            ringbuffer: Arc::new(RingBuffer::<T, Size>::new_empty()),
        }
    }

    fn push(&mut self, value: T) -> bool {
        unsafe {
            (*Arc::get_mut_unchecked(&mut self.ringbuffer)).push(value)
        }
    }

    fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<&T> {
        unsafe {
            (*Arc::get_mut_unchecked(&mut self.ringbuffer)).pop()
        }
    }

    fn is_full(&self) -> bool {
        self.ringbuffer.is_full()
    }

    fn is_empty(&self) -> bool {
        self.ringbuffer.is_empty()
    }
}
////////////////////// for test//////////////////////////
fn test_speed1() {
    let mut q: SharedRingBuffer<i32, 8> = SharedRingBuffer::new_empty();
    let mut t0 = std::time::SystemTime::now();
    let t = {
        let mut q = q.clone();
        std::thread::spawn(move || {
            loop {
                let t = match q.pop() {
                    None => {
                        // std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(10));
                        continue;
                    }
                    Some(res) => res
                };
                if *t == -1 {
                    break;
                }
                std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1));
            }
            let now = std::time::SystemTime::now();
            println!("res: {}", now.duration_since(t0).unwrap().as_millis());
        })
    };
    for i in 0..99 {
        loop {
            if q.push(i) {
                // std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(10));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    q.push(-1);
    t.join().unwrap();
}
```

When i addition `std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(10))` for q.push and q.pop method it is work well.

```
rustc 1.67.0-nightly (95a3a7277 2022-10-31)
binary: rustc
commit-hash: 95a3a7277b44bbd2dd3485703d9a05f64652b60e
commit-date: 2022-10-31
host: x86_64-pc-windows-msvc
release: 1.67.0-nightly
LLVM version: 15.0.4
```

I expect the RingBuffer can work well.
The equivalent code is：

```
fn test_speed2() {
    let (send, recv) = channel::<i32>();
    let mut is_run = SharedValue::new(true);
    let mut t0 = std::time::SystemTime::now();
    let t = {
        let is_run = is_run.clone();
        std::thread::spawn(move || {
            loop {
                let t = match recv.recv() {
                    Err(e) => {
                        break;
                    }
                    Ok(res) => res
                };
                if t == -1 {
                    break;
                }
                std::thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(1));
            }
            let now = std::time::SystemTime::now();
            // println!("res: {}", now.duration_since(t0).unwrap().as_millis());
        })
    };
    for i in 0..99 {
        send.send(i).unwrap();
    }
    send.send(-1).unwrap();
    t.join().unwrap();
}
```

I hope ringbuffer can replace channel to communicate between two threads,Because ringbuffer is lockfree and faster.

Comment: Could you please tell us what are the actual behaviour and expected behaviour? Since there is a lot of code in this post, it is very hard, if not impossible to see what the problem could be.

Comment: Nitpick: you can get rid of `array_init`, `array_init::array_init(|_| { unsafe { std::mem::zeroed() } })` is the same as `unsafe { std::mem::zeroed() }`.

Comment: Using `mem::zeroed()` for arbitrary `T` is unsound.

Comment: Writing `unsafe` code in rust requires much knowledge and obholding all invariants. For eample `std::mem::zeroed` is instant UB, because `0` is not a valid representation for all `T`. Same goes for `get_mut_unchecked`. Your code has undefined behavoir in it, so the compiler is free to do whatever he wants and therefore your code does not work. Rewrite it without using UB, then please ask your question again.

Comment: Even if this code didn't have any UB, it wouldn't be lock free. `get_mut` returns `Option<&mut T>` instead of just `&mut T` for a reason: something else could be accessing `T` already. Using `get_mut_unchecked` means that you have to deal with those cases yourself and if you don't the code will be buggy.

Comment: yes， ```mem::zeroed()``` is unsafe，but in this test case i used i32，which is safe,
the get_mut require owner is one,but i need it work on two thread, so i use ```get_mut_unchecked``` only. Since I use ringbuffer, it can ensure thread safety，In debug mode，It can work well，the main thread push value, sometime spawn thread pop value, but, when i run with --release it does not output as expected.

Comment: This codes are referenced from

 ```https://github.com/QuantumLeaps/lock-free-ring-buffer```

Comment: Because you use `i32` `mem::zeroed()` is not UB, but it is still _unsound_ because it is _possible_ to use your code with different types. And about the `get_mut_unchecked()`, this doesn't matter: once you call it with more than one owner you have instant UB and the compiler is allowed to do whatever it wants. If you're sure you're never accessing the same things at the same time you can use raw pointers and a custom implementation of `Arc` (or interior mutability). But your code will still be unsound as nothing gurantees that two threads won't `pop()` or `push()` at the same time.

Comment: And also, I think you do have a data race (although I haven't checked it through).

Comment: The same implementation works well in c++and python

Comment: You can refer to this

```https://github.com/QuantumLeaps/lock-free-ring-buffer```

Comment: @wengangyang If rust compiler says it won't work, then it **very likely** won't work in other languages as well.

Comment: Which reason seems to have been found，break the invariants of ```Arc::get_unchecked```
two threads sametime owner &RingBuffer, which broken Arc 's atomic counter, It may be the cause.

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze Not necessarily: it may be that `noalias` break things here.

Comment: What is noalias ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code causes undefined behavior by creating two mutable references to the same object at the same time via `Arc::get_mut_unchecked()`. It looks like this was even your intention, but it is blatantly violating Rust's rules. Even when using `unsafe`, you cannot violate the requirement that mutable references are *exclusive*.

Running your code with `cargo miri` reports this undefined behavior:

```
error: Undefined Behavior: Data race detected between Read on thread `<unnamed>` and Write on thread `main` at alloc1894+0x10
   --> bar/src/main.rs:45:12
    |
45  |         if self.idx_head == tail {
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Data race detected between Read on thread `<unnamed>` and Write on thread `main` at alloc1894+0x10
    |
    = help: this indicates a bug in the program: it performed an invalid operation, and caused Undefined Behavior
    = help: see https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html for further information
    = note: BACKTRACE:
    = note: inside `<RingBuffer<i32, 8> as Queue<i32>>::pop` at bar/src/main.rs:45:12
note: inside `<SharedRingBuffer<i32, 8> as Queue<i32>>::pop` at bar/src/main.rs:89:18
   --> bar/src/main.rs:89:18
    |
89  |         unsafe { (*Arc::get_mut_unchecked(&mut self.ringbuffer)).pop() }
    |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: inside closure at bar/src/main.rs:108:31
   --> bar/src/main.rs:108:31
    |
108 |                 let t = match q.pop() {
    |                               ^^^^^^^
```

You will need to rethink your design. You'll probably need a foundation like this to make it safe to modify between threads:

```
use std::cell::UnsafeCell;
use std::mem::MaybeUninit;
use std::sync::atomic::AtomicUsize;

pub struct RingBuffer<T, const SIZE: usize> {
    idx_head: AtomicUsize,
    idx_tail: AtomicUsize,
    m_data: [UnsafeCell<MaybeUninit<T>>; SIZE],
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This is actually caused by the CPU cache，The solution is as follows：

```
fn push(&mut self, value: T) -> bool {
    let mut head  = unsafe {
        std::ptr::read_volatile(&self.idx_head) + 1
    };
    let tail = unsafe {
        std::ptr::read_volatile(&self.idx_tail)
    };
    if head == Size {
        head = 0;
    }
    if head == tail {
        return false;
    }
    self.m_data[self.idx_head] = value;
    unsafe {
        std::ptr::write_volatile(&mut self.idx_head, head);
    }
    return true;
}

fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<&T> {
    let mut tail = unsafe {
        std::ptr::read_volatile(&self.idx_tail)
    };
    let head  = unsafe {
        std::ptr::read_volatile(&self.idx_head)
    };
    if head == tail {
        return None;
    }
    let res = &self.m_data[tail];
    tail += 1;
    if tail == Size {
        tail = 0;
    }
    unsafe {
        std::ptr::write_volatile(&mut self.idx_tail, tail);
    }
    return Some(res);
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect. The CPU cache is not to blame, rather Rust's mutable references *are exclusive* and thus code is generated that assumes that while a `&mut self` is currently held, nothing else can modify it (or even read it).